# Is there any way to export chrome develop tools data from api or command

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

can i get Chrome Developer Tools Network Panel'data  by  communicate with chrome remote debugging port ？
it can be saved as har formate file,but i want to save it by some script.

Answer (score 1):

You can right click on the Sources panel wheren you see the network data, and save the entire view as a HAR file, or a single file as a HAR file. And then you can import that exact data into chrome which will give you everything you had back from that specific data load.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to get your web app performance information back from your clients.

[`window.performance`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Navigation_timing) has a lot of information about how your page loaded and all timings for document ready and `DOMContentLoaded` and many other stuff in very high resolution.

Anyway that is not as detailed as *Network* panel in developer tools and if you really want to get that information back you should ask your user to grab that information manually and send it to you or ask them to install a chrome extension that does the job for you.